# Access Update query not running in VBA but runs manually

Tags: ms-access, vba

This part of code executes after logging in in the system in Access.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function updateShftDate()

On Error GoTo Macro6_Err
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryShiftDate", acViewNormal, acEdit

Macro6_Exit:
Exit Function

Macro6_Err:
MsgBox Error$
Resume Macro6_Exit
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

End Function
```

**QUERIES:**

qryShiftDate:

```
UPDATE tblShftDate, tblTasks SET tblTasks.TempShiftDate = [tblShftDate].[shftDate]
WHERE (((tblTasks.ExpectedTime) Like "*PM"));
```

The `tblShftDate` has `ID` and `shftDate` columns. `shftDate` column is bounded to a form when logging in. See picture below.

[image]
This runs only when the query is manually clicked but does not run in Access VBA. Any help would be great.

Comment: comment out the error trapping and you'll see an error message and set warnings to true, while testing.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav That helps :) It displays a warning `You are about to run an update query that will modify your data in your table` How can I overpass this?

Comment: that's fine, it's the warning you'd expect click ok, then it will display your sql error.

Comment: Is there a way I can set my preference to always OK, But sometimes even though I clicked OK, the query is still not executed?

Comment: Where is this function placed? Behind form or in standalone module? And where is it called? Please include trigger event that calls it.

Comment: @Parfait The function is in an stand alone module and is called inside another module. Let's say it's called under `cmdLogin` module. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must *execute* an action query:

```
Function updateShftDate()

    CurrentDb.Execute "qryShiftDate"

Exit Function
```

And you should *never* use string handling for date/time, thus:

```
WHERE Hour(tblTasks.ExpectedTime) >= 12;
```

Comment: I've already tried using the execute but that doesn't work either. And now I've added your correction, it also doesn't work :(

Comment: I can see that. I skipped your first line, but when I study it now, it is doesn't make sense to me. I'm surprised it should work when run manually.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It looks strange to me. But if it works for you, that's OK. And if it does "manually", so will the execute.

Comment: Is there a way I can run this automatically?

Comment: Yes. But how is determined by what you mean with automatically.

Comment: Mmm .. The query does not run when called in access VBA. The query only runs when clicked in access queries section; when the query is clicked

Comment: Then something else is going on. Did you remove the error handler?

Comment: Yes, this is the one displayed `You are about to run an update query that will modify your data in your table` How can I overpass this or always assume that the users choice is `OK`?

Comment: Then you are not using my code. `CurrentDb.Execute` will not pop this message.

Comment: I've used and tried it before but still unfortunate enough; it still doesn't work.

Comment: You can't both use CurrentDb.Execute and see the message, so double-check your code.